# Formula for sequence $\left(r_{k}\right)_{k=0}^{\infty}=(1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 25, 39, 61, 93,\cdots)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

The sequence 
$$
\left(r_{k}\right)_{k=0}^{\infty}=(1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 25, 39, 61, 93,\cdots)
$$
can be found at OEIS as sequence [A207641](https://oeis.org/A207641) and is related to Ramanujan theta functions.

Unfortunately there is no explicit formula for $r_{k}$ or I wasn't able to see it.

So I'm asking if there exists such expression and if so write it here or point to the appropriate sources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't expect there to be a (simple) closed form if there is none on OEIS... Why do you expect one?

Comment: It is referred there that its the 9th equation of the "The Lost Notebook and Other Unpublished Papers", but I didn't find it online...

Comment: According to the link you provided, it has the generating function $$f(q)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-q;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}q^n.$$ This is the special case $$f(q)=\,_1\phi_0[-q;;q,q],$$ where $_m\phi_n$ is the [basic hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series). I highly doubt there is a closed form.

Comment: [It's listed](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+3%2C+5%2C+9%2C+15%2C+25%2C+39%2C+61%2C+93&language=english&go=Search) in OEIS.

Comment: Of course we may use the $q$-binomial theorem $$_1\phi_0(a;q,z)=\frac{(az;q)_\infty}{(z;q)_\infty }$$ to get $$f(q)=\frac{(-q^2;q)_\infty}{(q;q)_{\infty}}$$

Comment: What would you do with an "explicit formula" for this sequence?

Comment: $\sum_{k\ge 0} r_k q^k = \frac1{(1+q)(1+2\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^n q^{n^2})}$